# Java Thread is WAITING(parking) state forever

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a function which will call to API, If there is any error as response from the API, I'm calling the same API by providing some interval using Thread.sleep(millis) for 3 times, It is executing for 1 or two times and blocking forever, Here is the sample thread dump

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000007d5903b20> (a java.lang.Thread)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post full stacktrace.

Comment: Check the trace, java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park is called, which "Disables the current thread for thread scheduling purposes unless the permit is available."  Check the documentation on how this can be unlocked ..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park().

Comment: I have this much log trace only @usualdeveloper,,@arunvg: I have gone through this doument...

Comment: If that is all the (relevant) information you can provide us, I don't think there is any chance that we can help you.

Comment: Thread dumps, stack traces, and sometimes even error messages mean nothing without source code.  It's best if you can post a Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example:  http://sscce.org/